# How to center a vector in latex

Tags: latex

I am using latex for my report. I am stuck in centering a vector. This is my latex code:

```
\begin{equation}
\centering
X_{i}=
$$\begin{bmatrix}
C_1\\
C_2\\
C_3\\
\vdots\\
\vdots\\
\vdots\\
\vdots\\
C_n\\
OlValue\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
\label{Vect}
\end{equation}
```

The centering command doesn't work. I tried several things but the vector is not on the center.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\noindent
X \dotfill X% To show the horizontal text width/margins

\begin{equation}
  X_i =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    C_1 \\ C_2 \\
    \vdots \\
    C_n
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Don't use `\centering` inside an `equation`. Also don't use `$$`...`$$`. The `equation` environment automatically centres its contents, period.